# How to filter computed value with computed value

Tags: vuex, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-card
      v-for="country in filteredData"
      :key="country"
    >
      <q-card-section>
        <div>{{ country.Country }}</div>
      </q-card-section>

    </q-card>
    <q-inner-loading
      :showing="summaryDataFetchStatus"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { defineComponent, computed, onMounted, watch } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "CovidSummaryDataComponent",
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    onMounted(() => {
      store.dispatch("CovidStore/updateCovidSummary");
    });

    const summaryData = computed(() => store.getters["CovidStore/summaries"]);
    const headerInputValue = computed(() => store.getters["CountrySearchBarStore/getSearchBarValue"]);
    const summaryDataFetchStatus = computed(() => store.getters["CovidStore/getSummaryDataFetchStatus"]);
    const filteredData = computed(() => summaryData.value.filter(country => country.Country.includes(headerInputValue.value)));
    

    return {
      filteredData,
      summaryData,
      headerInputValue ,
      summaryDataFetchStatus
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Hi all. I am trying to filter `summaryData` by `headerInputValue` but filteredData doesn't return array. It throws `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')` error. If i use `v-for="country in summaryData"` instead of `v-for="country in filteredData"` it work properly so it means `summaryData` is array. Then why i can't use filter on summaryData ?

Comment: Hi, your situation requires more debugging. Try using the dev tools or console.log the summary data to check whether it is actually an array. V-for on the summary data does not necessarily mean it is an array. V-for is not only used on an array it can be used on objects as well etc.

Comment: Yes you are right.It returns Proxy.So how can i filter summaryData in this case ?